# How prove this integral inequality $\min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)\ge-\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|dx$

Tags: integral-inequality

let $f(x)$ can change sign in $x\in [0,1]$ and is continuous derivative function, show that

> $$\min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)\ge-\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|dx$$

**My try**:since $f(x)$ change sign in $x\in [0,1]$,

then there exsit $\xi\in [0,1]$ such $f(\xi)=0$.
then

> $$\Longleftrightarrow \min_{x\in [0,1]}f(x)-f(\xi)\ge \int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|dx$$
>   then let
>   $$f(a)=\min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)$$
>   so
>   $$\Longrightarrow f(\xi)-f(a)\le\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|dx$$

then How to prove this inequality?

Thank you(maybe this problem have some methods) for your nice methods.

Answer (score 4):

If $x\in[0,1]$ then
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt\\
&\ge-\Bigl|\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt\Bigr|\\
&\ge-\int_0^x|f'(t)|\,dt\\
&\ge-\int_0^1|f'(t)|\,dt.
\end{align}$$

### Edit

I just realized that I made a mistake, since $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt$. The above is valid only if $f(0)=0$. If $f$ does not change sign, then the inequality may fail, as the example $f(x)=-1$ shows.

If $f(\xi)=0$ for some $\xi\in[0,1]$ and $\xi\le x\le1$ then
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_\xi^xf'(t)\,dt\\
&\ge-\Bigl|\int_\xi^xf'(t)\,dt\Bigr|\\
&\ge-\int_\xi^x|f'(t)|\,dt\\
&\ge-\int_0^1|f'(t)|\,dt.
\end{align}$$
Similarly if $0\le x\le\xi$.

Comment: Hello, this is $f(0)\neq 0$

Comment: I ha edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in[0,1]$ such that $f(a)=\min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)$. since $f$ change the sign there is  $z\in[0,1]$ such that $f(z)= 0$

We have $$0= f(z) \ge f(a)=\min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x) $$ hence,

$$ 0\le -f(a) = f(z) -f(a) =\int_a^zf'(t)dt \le \left|\int_a^zf'(t)dt\right| \le \int_0^1\left|f'(t)\right|dt$$
that is 
$$f(a)=\min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x) \ge - \int_0^1\left|f'(t)\right|dt$$